# Get top posts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have posts controller with action index :

```
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.all.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
    elsif params[:top]
      @posts = Post.all.top_posts.page(params[:page]).per(10)
    else
      @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
    end
  end
```

also I have a scope in my Post model:

```
scope :top_posts, lambda {order("posts.view DESC")}
```

When I go `to http://url/posts/top` i get this: `Couldn't find Post with id=top`
How can I implement top posts feature to blog? And what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`routes.rb`

```
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      get :top
      get :tag
    end
  end
```

`posts_controller.rb`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def top
    @posts = Post.all.top_posts.page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def tag
    @posts = Post.all.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
end
```

Comment: i've edited my post, this is the best practice from Rails Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes

Comment: Missing template posts/top, application/top

Comment: Thanks it works, also i have to add render :index to every action in contoller

Comment: Also you can render a template in each view.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/routes.rb`: put the route for your top products above the one for your show action, something like:

```
match '/posts/top', :to => 'posts#index', :as => :top, :top => true

...

match '/posts/:id', :to => 'posts#show', :as => :post
```

Or, if you are using resource routing, resource route should go after your "top posts" route.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot to add `top` parameter to the first route: `match '/posts/top', :to => 'posts#index', :as => :top, :top => true`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Also, this route doesn't include paging and you'll need a separate route for the tag filtering. Let me know if you need more precise explanations.